# How to make sticky sidebars without intersecting eachother

Tags: html, css

I have two navigation bars that are sticky. The problem is that they both intersect in the top left corner of the page, and the side nav bar intersects the top one, blocking the button. I've tried incresing the padding, but there is still an invisible space where the two nav bars intersect. Wht I want to do, is to have the side bar below the top bar and that they don't intersect andblock part of the button. Here is my code so far:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
 
 
 height: 100%;
    width: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.icon-bar a {
     
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #white;
    display: block;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.mainsbar {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .icon-bar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .icon-bar a {font-size: 18px;}
}


body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
 overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}



.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.main {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="background-color:#7f8fa8;">

<div class="main">


 <div class="icon-bartop">
   <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
   <a href="#news"><i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
 </div>



 <div id="home">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <div class="icon-bar">
     <a class="active" href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
     <a href="javascript:getPrices();"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.wolframalpha.com/"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
     <a href="https://www.amazon.com/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
   </div>
  </div>



  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Search Form -->
  
  
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="news">
  <h1 align="center">Test</h1>
 </div>

</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Try this code .icon-bar{top: 84px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your top position to 84px... since you are using position fixed and you can calculate your height using cal()..

```js
console.log('Loading')
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
 
 
 height: calc(100% - 84px);
    width: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 84px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.icon-bar a {
     
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #white;
    display: block;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.mainsbar {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .icon-bar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .icon-bar a {font-size: 18px;}
}


body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
 overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}



.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.main {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="background-color:#7f8fa8;">

<div class="main">


 <div class="icon-bartop">
   <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
   <a href="#news"><i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
 </div>



 <div id="home">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <div class="icon-bar">
     <a class="active" href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
     <a href="javascript:getPrices();"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.wolframalpha.com/"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
     <a href="https://www.amazon.com/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
   </div>
  </div>



  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Search Form -->
  
  
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="news">
  <h1 align="center">Test</h1>
 </div>

</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('Loading')
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4CAF50e;
  border: none;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {margin:10}

.icon-bar {
 
 
 height: 100%;
    width: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 83px;
}

.icon-bar a {
     
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #white;
    display: block;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #4289b5;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.mainsbar {
    margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .icon-bar {padding-top: 15px;}
    .icon-bar a {font-size: 18px;}
}


body{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a{
  
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 3;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FC2121;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;  
}

body {margin:0;}

.icon-bartop {
 overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: auto;
}

.icon-bartop a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bartop a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}



.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.main {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body style="background-color:#7f8fa8;">

<div class="main">


 <div class="icon-bartop">
   <a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
   <a href="#news"><i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
 </div>



 <div id="home">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <div class="icon-bar">
     <a class="active" href="#search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
     <a href="javascript:getPrices();"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a> 
     <a href="https://www.wolframalpha.com/"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></a>
     <a href="https://www.amazon.com/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a> 
   </div>
  </div>



  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Search Form -->
  
  
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="news">
  <h1 align="center">Test</h1>
 </div>

</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Use `margin-top` instead of `padding-top`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change the value of top

```
.icon-bar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 84px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #555;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```